# How do I remove DIV tags with style attributes from XML file?

Tags: xml, regex

I have a huge Wordpress XML export. Unfortunately, some bastard managed to inject code into the installation and injected DIVs into the content.
Now I want to clean that mess up. Here's what it looks like:

```
<p>Normal Text</p>
<div style="position:absolute;top:-9660px;left:-4170px;"><a href="http://insane.link.com">Insane Linktext</a></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:-2460px;left:-5370px;"><a href="http://insane.link.com">Another Insane Linktext</a></div>
<p>Normal good people's brains' text</p>
```

I thought about using some regex expression to match the DIVs containing a STYLE attribute. Available tools are Aptana or other TextEditors and a PHP Server as well as a OSX Terminal. Any Suggestions for this?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you: It will match the divs that you provided above:

```
<div style="[a-zA-Z0-9-:;]+"><a href="[a-z:/.]+">[a-zA-Z ]+</a></div>
```

However, it will only match a `div > a > text` pattern and only divs that have a style attribute and nothing else.

You should be able to do a find-and-replace using most HTML editors (Dreamweaver and Notepad++ both allow it)

Comment: yeah, that's the right approach and found already some. but the markup differs a little sometimes, so I'm okay with just matching just the DIVs, not the As. I tried `<div style="[a-zA-Z0-9-:;]+">('.*?')</div>` - but that doesn't find anything.

Comment: OK, I just found the solution that works fine for me: `<div style="[a-zA-Z0-9-:;]+">.*</div>` using Editra editor. Thanks for pointing me into that direction!

Comment: I must post the obligatory health warning regarding regex and XML http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/169346

Comment: I prefer my WP export's health over the XHTML/XML regex health ;) However the regex health warning struck something within me :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not using regex, but using a real XML parser. For example, since you're on OS X and thus have Ruby installed already you can clean up your HTML with:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'                      # Use `sudo gem install nokogiri` first
html = Nokogiri.HTML(IO.read(ARGV[0]))  # read and parse the HTML document
html.css('div[style]').remove           # destroy all <div style="...">...</div>
File.open(ARGV[1],'w'){ |f| f << html } # write the html to disk as a new file
```

You'll first need to install Nokogiri per the comment.

Then, save the above as "clean_divs.rb" and then type `ruby clean_divs.rb my.html my_fixed.html` (where the first is the name of the file to read and the second is the name of the file to write).

*If you want to be more precise in your destruction, you can use XPath to select the elements to destroy, e.g. `html.xpath('//div[@style][a]').remove` to find only divs that have a style attribute and an `<a>` direct child element.*

Comment: thanks for the tutorial, I preferred just using the editor, but I save this for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modified [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with an empty template for those `<div>` elements in order to remove them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!--default processing for content is to copy forward -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--remove the rogue div elements -->
    <xsl:template match="div[@style]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to apply XSL transformations. Do I use an editor, a browser or a server to do the transformations?